# Reverse MX A records (PTR) always error after are set G Suite MX records

Tags: dns, dns-servers, mx, google-workspace

If I check website at [intodns.com](https://intodns.com) I always get error on Reverse MX A records (PTR) **after** I set the following MX records to G Suite (old Google Apps):

- 1   aspmx.l.google.com
- 5   alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
- 5   alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
- 10   alt3.aspmx.l.google.com
- 10   alt4.aspmx.l.google.com

**Result:**

[image]

1. I have a dedicated server, the rDNS are set and have no errors till
   I do not declare MX records to G Suite.
2. The error persist after 72 hours, so is not about a propagation issue.
3. Doesn't matter if I keep the rDNS set by Data Center or if I set the
   rDNS to point to domain. The same error!
4. SPF / DKIM are set for that domain.
5. In WHM Email Routing set to: Remote Mail Exchange.

**Email work correctly** via G Suite, no errors or spam issue when sending and receiving emails!

What is funny that even Google.com receive the same error at [intodns.com/google.com](https://intodns.com/google.com)

Anyone able to set MX records to G Suite and to do not get this error?

Comment: I've never needed reverse DNS to work for my website.   I don't think you need to pay attention to that error to get your website working.

Comment: You should put the PTR record at the IP level, the domain is a plus but it is actually handled from the IP administrator or who it is actually allocated. You should perform here this action rather than in any server, by the way it should be also there. The should be there, on where the Ip is actually at, into the device. In this case, the IP is owned by Google.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known thing https://serverfault.com/questions/915142/reverse-dns-does-not-match-smtp-banner-g-suite -

Here is a long explanation that rDNS is not required for every device https://serverfault.com/questions/612833/do-internet-standards-require-reverse-dns-for-every-device

I was curious about this and had a look at the rDNS of some domains using gsuite that I manage as a webhost and found the same warning.  It all works.  I am not concerned about it.